# Insert value missing in mock content resolver

Tags: android, junit, android-contentprovider

I created a concrete class extending the ProviderTestCase2, and I'm writing test methods to test content provider's implementation of insert, delete, query, update, getType.

I used `getMockContentResolver` and passed in some random value, like

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("key1", "value1");
cv.put("key2", "value2");

Uri uri = getMockContentResolver.insert(table.content_uri, cv);
//table.content_uri defined earlier
assertNotNull(uri);
```

but when I run the test, I found the trace showing:

```
INSERT INTO table.content_uri("key1","key2") VALUES(?,?);
```

I'm curious where did the values go. Anyone knows how to check the testing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question marks are used as placeholders for SQLite queries in Android.  The content values are substituted in automatically

Comment: is there a way to check values i inserted? i checked my database from the console, but no test database/tables were created. and it seems i can't find related document showing my dummy data would be inserted as is.

Comment: I can't find any documentation either :( only [this which you already have](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/contentprovider_testing.html)